# regex expression to extract a string

Tags: java, regex

i want to extract ***[{"type":"MAPPINGTYPE","target":1,"source":0},{"type":"OWNEDOBJECTS","target":3,"source":0},{"type":"APIFILES","target":2,"source":1}]*** from the following string :

```
String json="links":[{"type":"MAPPINGTYPE","target":1,"source":0},{"type":"OWNEDOBJECTS","target":3,"source":0},{"type":"APIFILES","target":2,"source":1}],
```

im using the following code without result:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[(.*?)]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(json);
if (matcher.find())
{
   System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

the original probleme is the following: i havea JSONfile that is litlle messed up:

```
{
    "links":[{"type":"MAPPINGTYPE","target":1,"source":0},{"type":"OWNEDOBJECTS","target":3,"source":0},{"type":"APIFILES","target":2,"source":1}],
    "nodes":[{"label":["ClassDefinition","_ClassDefinition","_AbstractEntity"],"name":"HexStringParser"}],
    "links":[{"type":"MAPPINGTYPE","target":1,"source":0},{"type":"OWNEDOBJECTS","target":3,"source":0},{"type":"APIFILES","target":2,"source":1}],
    "nodes":[{"label":["ClassDefinition","_ClassDefinition","_AbstractEntity"],"name":"HexStringParser"}]
}
```

as you can see there is a duplucation of links and nodes i would like to merge them (not delete the duplication) to have a JSON like this :

```
{
    "links":[{"type":"MAPPINGTYPE","target":1,"source":0},{"type":"OWNEDOBJECTS","target":3,"source":0},{"type":"APIFILES","target":2,"source":1},{"type":"MAPPINGTYPE","target":1,"source":0},{"type":"OWNEDOBJECTS","target":3,"source":0},{"type":"APIFILES","target":2,"source":1}],
    "nodes":[{"label":["ClassDefinition","_ClassDefinition","_AbstractEntity"],"name":"HexStringParser"},{"label":["ClassDefinition","_ClassDefinition","_AbstractEntity"],"name":"HexStringParser"}],
}
```

i have tried the json parser

```
Map<String,String[]> map = new HashMap<String,String[]>();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
    //convert JSON string to Map
    map = mapper.readValue(json, 
    new TypeReference<HashMap<String,String[]>>(){});
    System.out.println(map);

    } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but i get this stack trace:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String[] out of VALUE_STRING token
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@3d0b8bc1; line: 1, column: 219]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.mappingException(StdDeserializationContext.java:219)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.mappingException(StdDeserializationContext.java:212)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.PrimitiveArrayDeserializers$StringDeser.handleNonArray(PrimitiveArrayDeserializers.java:153)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.PrimitiveArrayDeserializers$StringDeser.deserialize(PrimitiveArrayDeserializers.java:119)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.PrimitiveArrayDeserializers$StringDeser.deserialize(PrimitiveArrayDeserializers.java:107)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBind(MapDeserializer.java:319)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:249)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:33)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2732)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1870)
    at com.MyAppConverter.MapTool.HomeController.checkMapping(HomeController.java:174)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:146)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:279)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Why not just use a JSON parser?

Comment: is it a valid Java string and JSON string?

Comment: You need to escape the brackets.  ala `Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]")`

Comment: @Reimeus how would i use it exaclty ??,thnx

Comment: Search for JSON parse example. Several examples available online

Comment: @Reimeus i edited my question , if you can can look into it it would be great , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pattern: **"\\[.*\\]"**

Example:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[.*\\]");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(json);
    if (matcher.find())
    {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape  `[`, `]` characters because `[` is a special character in regex which refers the start of a character class. So this `[(.*?)]` will match a single character from the given list whether it may be `.` or `(` or `*` or `)` or `?` .

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(json);
if (matcher.find())
{
   System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

You don't need to use capturing group.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[.*?\\]");
```

OR

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[[^\\]]*\\]");
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like JSON string. Proper use `Jackson` or `GSON` JSON API to extract.

[Tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-map-to-from-json-jackson/)

Convert JSON string to `Map<String,String>` and get the desired field.

```
String json = "{\"name\":\"mkyong\", \"age\":\"29\"}";

Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

try {

    //convert JSON string to Map
    map = mapper.readValue(json, 
        new TypeReference<HashMap<String,String>>(){});

    System.out.println(map);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Using `GSON` API:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {}.getType();
Map<String, String> map=new Gson().fromJson(json, type);
System.out.println(map.get("links"));
```

Here is the valid JSON string:

```
{
    "links": [
        {
            "type": "MAPPINGTYPE",
            "target": 1,
            "source": 0
        },
        {
            "type": "OWNEDOBJECTS",
            "target": 3,
            "source": 0
        },
        {
            "type": "APIFILES",
            "target": 2,
            "source": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: i have updated my post if you can look into it i would be gratefull

Comment: first use `Map<String,Object>` then check the type of value `Object` and based on its type change the `Map`. In this way you can get the correct type of value or better use **POJO** class as value like `Map<String,MY_POJO>`

Answer (score 0):

Just use one `\` to scape the `[` or `]` chars, cause they're reserved in regex:

`\[(.*?)\]`

Comment: what is difference between your regex and Avnish's regex?

Comment: Have you compiled the code? You need to put one extra backspace to escape existing backspace.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the pure regex is:
`\[(.*?)\]`
not the compiled one.